# Export data to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, data-import

I have a SQL Server database with near real-time updated consumer data. Other than using an SFTP or Mulesoft, how can I export it to my contact list in Marketing Cloud? Using a connector, API, or ... ?